# asp.net 3.5 ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a webpage with filter selects at the top, a search button and a ListView with custom pager (witch is a Repeater witch contains LinkButtons with page numbers) at the bottom.

When I select filters and click the search button, I put the results in a List<> and DataBinding them at ListView. The function witch returns the results has two properties that are StartIndex and PageSize. So when I click a page I call again the function with new PageIndex. Sometimes the results need more columns from the ListView.
So I create two classes (ResultsLayoutTemplate.cs, ResultsItemTemplate.cs) to design the layout for ListView.

The problem is when I select a page (custom pager of ListView) whitch the results need more columns to ListView, the header of table does not change the columns and keeps the previous page header design. Lines have the right columns.
For example in first page ListView has 8 columns and in second page ListView must have 13 columns. But it keeps 8 columns for the header. The same happen when the third page need 8 columns it appears 13 from the previous page. The problem is only on the header.

Here's the code.

```
    protected void ListView1_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    results = Session["results"] as List<Res>;
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["columns"] = results.Max(i => i.columns.Count);
    }

    ListView lv = sender as ListView;
    ListView1.LayoutTemplate = new ResultsLayoutTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);
    ListView1.ItemTemplate = new ResultsItemTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);
    ListView1.AlternatingItemTemplate = new AlterResultsItemTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);

    Control newlayoutContainer = new Control();
    lv.LayoutTemplate = new ResultsLayoutTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);
    lv.LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(newlayoutContainer);

    var usercontrol = newlayoutContainer.Controls[0];
    usercontrol.ID = "MyLayout";
    lv.Controls.Add(newlayoutContainer);
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    bool isNum = Int32.TryParse(Session["page"].ToString(), out num);

    if ((Int32.Parse(Session["page"].ToString()) > 0) && (isNum))
    {
        results = Session["results"] as List<Res>;
        Session["platos"] = results.Max(i => i.quadruplette.Count);

        ListView1.Items.Clear();
        ListView1.ItemTemplate = new ResultsItemTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);
        ListView1.AlternatingItemTemplate = new AlterResultsItemTemplate((int)Session["columns"]);

        ListView1.DataSource = results;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void lbPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
    int num;
    bool isNum = Int32.TryParse(btn.Text, out num);
    if (isNum)
    {
        Session["page"] = btn.Text;
    }
    results = GetResults(Filters, (Int32.Parse(Session["page"].ToString()) - 1) * PageSize, PageSize);

        Session["results"] = results;
        Session["columns"] = results.Max(i => i.columns.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure i understand the question, but it sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Why not use the asp.net pagercontrol and just define the layout to fit what you need. Then use a sqldatasource control with a WHERE clause bound to your filter controls. Then bind that to the listview. Then have the sqldatasource rebind when you click the go button. any special operations that need to be performed before the bind actually happens can happen in the Selecting event.